# Insulate wall with brick exposed

Tags: insulation, garage, brick

I'm currently redoing my garage and encountered the issue of a wall in the garage with brick exposed and 2x4 as framing. i want to insulate this wall as we are planning to add a home gym and the temperatures would range anywhere between -10 to 100 (we are in Zone 6b) outside. Currently it would depend heavily on the outside temperature so thought adding insulation to all walls would help with some temperature control. How should i go about insulating this wall as i think I cannot directly place batts over the brick? There is some gap between the brick and the framing like about an inch or less. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: probably need humidity barrier first

Comment: How old is this structure? Old case-hardened bricks and lime mortar are treated differently from modern bricks and concrete-based mortar... You might want to consider repointing first, but that would be better done before the studs went in.

Comment: Are you going to HVAC this garage?

Comment: House is built in or around 1966. @keshlam

Comment: @Huesmann No HVAC, just planning to use the heater in Winter so it can be decently warm for the workout.

Comment: @Ruskes Humidity barrier as in 6 mil or 10 mil plastic sheet? or something else? Do you have link for the product?

Comment: @keshlam  I'm working with an existing structure. The studs and all are added around the time the house was built. I'm planning to add insulation to the wall to keep the temperature under control for workouts

Comment: Humidity layer comes s part of the fiberglass insulation

Comment: Again: do you know what type the bricks and mortar are?  If not, you may need to send a sample of the mortar for analysis... or assume it's lime mortar and that airflow is required to allow the mortar to transpire.

Comment: @keshlam no I do not know what type they are. But as far as I can tell it looks like regular cement not lime